# Parse JSON with arduino to turn on LED

Tags: arduino-uno, shields, wifi

Hi i'm trying to parse JSON resposne from webserver in my arduino in order to turn on and off a LED light. I'm using the wifi client repeating example to make a get request to my server:

http://arduino.cc/en/Tutorial/WiFiWebClientRepeating

Here is what I get printed back from the serial port

```
connecting...
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: Sun, 06 Apr 2014 01:14:37 GMT
Server: Apache
X-Powered-By: PHP/5.5.10
Cache-Control: no-cache
X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN
Set-Cookie: expires=Sun, 06-Apr-2014 03:14:37 GMT; Max-Age=7200; path=/; httponly
Connection: close
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Content-Type: application/json

19
{"lightstatus":"on"}
0
```

How do i parse the JSON portion of this response only so that I can use it to control my LED?

Thanks

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I'm aware of a few JSON parsing libraries for Arduino.

- [aJSON](https://github.com/interactive-matter/aJson)
- [Arduino JSON Parser](https://github.com/bblanchon/ArduinoJsonParser)
- [JSON Arduino](https://github.com/not404/json-arduino)

I've never used any of these but I did do some simple JSON parsing in a project I'm working on so I'll show you how I did that.

NOTE: I'm reading serial data using the software serial library. You'll need to change this code to work for you. This will only work on very simple JSON strings. It's *very* limited but if that's all you're parsing then it'll work.

Example of JSON response from server:

```
{"id":"TEST1","lat":"38.56050207","lng":"-121.42158374","total":"3","available":"2"}
```

First, only read data between curly braces.

```
String response = "";
bool begin = false;
while (SIM900.available() || !begin) {

    char in = SIM900.read();

    if (in == '{') {
        begin = true;
    }

    if (begin) response += (in);

    if (in == '}') {
        break;
    }

    delay(1);
}
```

This code reads data one byte at a time and once it gets an open brace, it starts saving it into `response`. When it gets a closing brace, it ends it. So here's a clear limitation, you can only have one set of opening/closing braces in your string.

Once I have the string, I use `indexOf` and `substring` to extract relevant information:

```
start = response.indexOf("id\":\"") + 5;
end = start + 5;
nodeId = response.substring(start, end);
```

This code sets `start` to the beginning of `id":"` + 5 characters in the string. It's +5 because that's how long `id":"` is. So `start` points to `TEST1` in the JSON string. In my system, the ID is always going to be 5 characters long so end is `start + 5`. I then use `substring` to extract that.

Again, before anyone starts down voting me for this horrible solution: if you know exactly what you're working with, and understand the limitations of this code, then this is not a bad solution. It's a solution that gets the job done.

Comment: The JSON example you give does not look like "good" JSON, e.g. numeric values should normally not be quoted as strings.

Comment: +1 for the list of potentially usable libraries for JSON. I am surprised no library is based on a callback function approach, that would be called during parsing (much more efficient memory-wise).

Comment: At least you're conscious that your code sample is horrible:-) Of course it gets the job done, but it is not readable (by someone else qnd even by yourself in 6 months) and hence not maintainable.

Comment: @jfpoilpret I'm out of memory on the chip so I've had to cut corners in some places. At least it's heavily commented.

Comment: I understand; but I wonder if `String` usage does not make the memory situation worse (yes, `String` in Arduino is my pet peeve).

Comment: I think from the list of libraries you provided it would be nice to comment it's main features (eg: Arduino JSON Parser not using mallocs)

Answer (score 7):

I have programmed a class that will receive char by char the JSON document. It only will store in memory a few bytes for known JSON structure using a state machine and the results you need. So you can query the class for the results you want and will process the JSON.

Its ideal for your purpose. I have used for connecting to a weather service that returns a json:

```
static const char* queries[] = { "list.0.deg", "list.0.weather.0.main"};
StreamJsonReader jsonreader(queries, 2); // 2 queries    
while(char c  =  read()){
      jsonreader.process_char(c);
}

cout << jsonreader.results[0] << endl;
cout << jsonreader.results[1] << endl;
```

Check this blog post I just wrote: http://web.biicode.com/blog/big-json-on-arduino.

Source code is [here](https://www.biicode.com/lasote/blocks/lasote/stream_json_reader/branches/master) in Biicode.

Answer (score 2):

I wrote a parser for the PIC that has very low ram use because it works directly with char pointers and does not build a tree structure. If you ask to get item N of a list, it gives you an actual pointer into the direct JSON file right at the start of item N of the list. Then you can ask what type of object the pointer represents, etc. It's buggy and doesn't support floats and I think has a few other limitations(twas a long time ago) but it's all on github:https://github.com/EternityForest/OpenFortune-fortune-like-text-generator
You'll need to look in libfortune which is part of the C version.

Answer (score 1):

I wrote a simple JSON-RPC library (on top of aJson) with example of how to turn a led on with JSON-RPC procedure call:

- Code: https://github.com/cloud-rocket/arduino-json-rpc
- Documentation: http://www.cloud-rocket.com/2014/03/serial-json-rpc-server-arduino/

Comment: Can you add some more information into your answer in case the link to the code/documentation changes...